# ReRender a different card view onPropertyPaneFieldChanged in Adaptive Card Extension ( spfx )

Tags: spfx, spfx-extensions, spfx-custom-property-pane, adaptive-cards, microsoft-viva

I have an SPFX project based on adaptive card template of yeoman generator.
It contains two Card views,  Normal and Error. Use case is simple, in case Title property is empty show the Error Cardview otherwise the Normal view.

This functionality works ok if i refresh the page post property change. But since my webpart is in reactive mode, i expect the card view to also change the moment Title property is empty/non empty. User should not have to refresh the page to see the correct card

Secondly, i dont understand why `this.setState` function call in `OnPropertyPaneFieldChanged` is not triggering this change ? my AdaptiveCardExtension class is below ..any help?

```
export interface IMeetingsAdaptiveCardExtensionProps {
  title: string;
  description: string;
  iconProperty: string;
}

export interface IMeetingsAdaptiveCardExtensionState {
  description: string;
  cardToShow: string;
}

const CARD_VIEW_REGISTRY_ID: string = 'Meetings_CARD_VIEW';
const CARD_VIEW_ERROR_ID: string = 'Meetings_CARD_VIEW_ERROR';

export const QUICK_VIEW_REGISTRY_ID: string = 'Meetings_QUICK_VIEW';

export default class MeetingsAdaptiveCardExtension extends BaseAdaptiveCardExtension<
  IMeetingsAdaptiveCardExtensionProps,
  IMeetingsAdaptiveCardExtensionState
> {
  private _deferredPropertyPane: MeetingsPropertyPane | undefined;

  public onInit(): Promise<void> {


   
    this.state = {
      description: this.properties.description,
      cardToShow: this.properties.title?CARD_VIEW_REGISTRY_ID :CARD_VIEW_ERROR_ID
    };

     
    // ALL the cards need to be regiested here.. 
    this.cardNavigator.register(CARD_VIEW_REGISTRY_ID, () => new CardView());
    this.cardNavigator.register(CARD_VIEW_ERROR_ID, () => new ErrorCard());

    // ALL the views to be registered here....
    this.quickViewNavigator.register(QUICK_VIEW_REGISTRY_ID, () => new QuickView());

    return Promise.resolve();
  }

  public get title(): string {
    return this.properties.title;
  }

  protected get iconProperty(): string {
    return this.properties.iconProperty || require('./assets/SharePointLogo.svg');
  }


  protected onPropertyPaneFieldChanged(propertyPath: string, oldValue: any, newValue: any): void {

    console.log(`onPropertyPaneFieldChanged text`)

    // TOTALK: setState rerenders the wp
    if(propertyPath==="title" && newValue){     
      this.setState({
        ...this.state,
        cardToShow:CARD_VIEW_REGISTRY_ID
      })
    }
      else{     
      this.setState({
        ...this.state,
        cardToShow:CARD_VIEW_ERROR_ID
      })   
    }   

   
    this.context.propertyPane.refresh();
    this.renderCard()

      
  }
  protected loadPropertyPaneResources(): Promise<void> {

    

    return import(
      /* webpackChunkName: 'Meetings-property-pane'*/
      './MeetingsPropertyPane'
    )
      .then(
        (component) => {
          this._deferredPropertyPane = new component.MeetingsPropertyPane();
        }
      );
  }

  protected renderCard(): string | undefined {
    //the value is updated correctly in state
    console.log(`card is ${this.state.cardToShow}`) 

    return this.state.cardToShow;
  }


  protected getPropertyPaneConfiguration(): IPropertyPaneConfiguration {
    return this._deferredPropertyPane!.getPropertyPaneConfiguration();
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure ```this.context.propertyPane.refresh(); this.renderCard()``` lines are necessary? The sample from [cwparsons/spfx-custom-card-designer-ace](https://github.com/cwparsons/spfx-custom-card-designer-ace) doesn't need that when changing CardViews. Since that repo has this working, maybe you might want to check what the differences are between both implementations.

Comment: thanks a lot , will check